# Jhipster 4.6.2 Microservices

Tags: jhipster

I have created a "customer" microservice with an entity

Then I create that same entity in the gateway:

```
Do you want to generate this entity from an existing microservice? Y
```

And I create all the html and js. What I see is that the Angular service goes directly to the Microservice.

```
  private resourceUrl = 'customer/api/customer-xxx';
```

Should not I call my Gateway and turn to the Microservice?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/api/customer-xxx` is the API endpoint of your microservice, `/customer/api/customer-xxx` is the API endpoint exposed  by the gateway which uses application name as a prefix and proxifies requests to the microservice endpoint.